# How to use MassTransit with RabbitMQ for .net framework 4.6.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I want to use MassTransit with RabbitMQ for .net framework 4.6.1 project. I've followed this  [official doc](https://masstransit-v6.netlify.app/usage/configuration.html#owin-pipeline-webapi2) to setup in WebAPI2 project using OWIN, but it is showing errors while building. It seems like i've missed to install some packages. This [official doc](https://masstransit-v6.netlify.app/usage/configuration.html#owin-pipeline-webapi2) doesnot mention which packages i need to install, also VS2022 intellisense does not suggests the missing packages to install. Errors shown on these lines:

```
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
```

And another problem is in this line: `var busHandle = bus.Start();`
Here, `bus.Start()` methods returns nothing(void). That's why cannot assign the result to busHandle.

NOTE: I am using these nuget packages
MassTransit 6.3.2
MassTransit.RabbitMQ 6.3.2

Answer (score 1):

After some google search I've figured it out: need to install nuget package `Autofac.WebApi2.Owin` `v5.0.0`.
Also note that need to install package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` for OWIN to work and `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`.

For the second error, in this code `var busHandle = bus.Start();` `bus.Start()` doesnot return any result that's why I decided to call it like this:
`bus.Start();`

And, one more
In the `Configuration` method of `Startup.cs` file, need to add this line (before `builder.Build()`)

```cs
           // Register anything else you might need...
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // Build the container
            var container = builder.Build();
```

I hope this helps you.

If you want a complete step-by-step solutions, please let me know.

Happy coding...